# How do I access data from a model the present model belongs to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models Issue and Split.

Issues have many Splits, a Split belongs to an Issue. Here is the code for the two models:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :publication
    has_many :splits
    has_many :issue_split_geographies
    belongs_to :medium

    validates :name, :start_date, :status, presence: true
end

class Split < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :issue
    has_and_belongs_to_many :geographies 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :media 
end
```

I know how to access split information from an issue in my Issue views by doing @issue.split.name if I want to get a split name in my issue view.

I'm having problems figuring out how to go the other way. How can I show Issue information in a Split view?

@split.issue.target gives me undefined method `issue' for nil:NilClass

split.issue.target gives me undefined local variable or method `split' for

issue.target gives me "undefined local variable or method `issue' for"

I'm trying to show the target value for the issue on the splits index page so I can determine how many more splits to add to reach my target.

It seems like I'm missing something obvious. But, I'm a bit of a noob.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you defined `@split`? Please post the related code.

Comment: And in your example, does `@split` have an `issue_id`?

Comment: I'm showing this on the index page so an issue_id isn't assigned yet. I'm literally just trying to show the value of the the issue target value so the end user can decide which splits to assign to the issue to reach that value. Think of it as adding gas to a car gas tank. I'm trying to display the capacity of the gas tank so the user can determine which gas cans to add to the tank so it will be full.

Comment: `@split.issue` won't work if your `splits` table does not have an `issue_id`.

Comment: My splits `table` does have `issue_id`. The problem is that on the index page I'm showing all splits. What I'm trying to display on this page is the `issue.target` value

Comment: To do so, you will do: `@split.issue.target` which you are already doing. But, the problem is `@split` is `nil`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@split.issue.target
```

is the right way to go as your *split* `belongs_to` *issue*. So, `@split.issue` is fine. Just make sure you define `@split` in your corresponding controller's action and you have `issue_id` in your `splits` table.

But, as you mention: `@issue.split.name`, which should not be correct as your *issue* `has_many` *splits*. It should be like: `@issue.splits.first.name`

Your error message:

```
@split.issue.target gives me undefined method `issue' for nil:NilClass
```

means that `@split` is `nil`. So, define `@split` in your correspnding controller's action/method. Something like this:

```
@split = Split.first
```

Then, it should work.

Comment: I've added `@split = nil` to my splits controller for my index method (which is what I think you said I needed to do) and I have `@split.issue.target` in my index view. But, I'm still getting `undefined method issue' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: No, I did not say you have to do this: `@split = nil`. sorry for the confusion. It can't be that. You have to set `@split` with a value something like this: `@split = Split.first`

Comment: Got it. Works perfectly. Thanks!